# Finding the minimum and maximum populations

Tags: python-3.x, max, min

This is my code. When I try and get the minimum and the maximum populated country's to be returned it prints the first country from the csv file for both the maximum and minimum populated country.

```
import csv
import math

def main(file_name, region):

    data = []
    
    with open(file_name, 'r') as file:
        reader = csv.DictReader(file)   #Reads the CSV file and returns a list of dictionaries containing the data
        for row in reader:
            data.append(row)
            
        countries = []
    
    
        for row in data:
            if row['Regions'] == region and float(row['Net Change']) > 0:   #Returns a list of countries in a specific region with positive net change in population
                countries.append(row['Name'])
        #return countries
    
    
                min_population = math.inf
                max_population = -math.inf
                
                min_country = None
                max_country = None
                
    
                if row['Name'] in countries:    #Returns the country with minimum and maximum population in the given list of countries
                    population = int(row['Population(2020)'])
                    if population < min_population:
                        min_population = population
                        min_country = row['Name']
                    if population > max_population:
                        max_population = population
                        max_country = row['Name']
                return min_country, max_country
```

I was expecting it to provide two different countries which are the maximum and minimum populated country's

Comment: The first time through your for loop there is only one country in countries. Essentially, your issue is the use of `if row['Name'] in countries` which looks to be unneeded as well as then `countries.append(row['Name'])`

Comment: Please see "[ask]", "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)" and "[mre]" and all their linked pages. We need to be able to duplicate the problem, but you have not provided sample data.

Answer (score 0):

There are s number of things we can look at to get this working. You have a skeleton of a good solution and I think we just need to tweak things slightly.

The two things I am going to change are:

1. lets read and filter the data in one step
2. move the initialization of min/max variables out of our loop

```py
import csv
import math

def main(file_name, region):
    min_population = math.inf
    max_population = -math.inf
    min_country = None
    max_country = None

    with open(file_name, 'r') as file:
        countries = [
            row
            for row
            in csv.DictReader(file)
            if row['Regions'] == region and float(row['Net Change']) > 0
        ]

    for row in countries:
        population = int(row['Population(2020)'])

        if population < min_population:
            min_population = population
            min_country = row['Name']

        if population > max_population:
            max_population = population
            max_country = row['Name']

    return min_country, max_country
```